# Select columns based on condition in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to find a solution to select columns in Snowflake based on a condition.
For example I only want to select columns which contain the string "id" or only the numeric columns.

Is there any solution for these cases?

Best regards

Comment: The answer is:  `WHERE`.  If you want a more specific answer, provide sample data and more explanation of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something as below. Following procedure query the account usage schema and generate a column list and then return a query based on table and column type. This can be extended

```js
create or replace procedure column_list (TBL_NAME STRING, COL_TYPE STRING)
 returns string
language javascript

as
$$

  

  var sql_stmt = `select listagg(column_name,',') as col1 from snowflake.account_usage.columns 
where table_name = 'FOO' and table_schema = 'PUBLIC' and DATA_TYPE = '` + COL_TYPE + `' and DELETED IS NULL;`;
var create_log_table_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_stmt });
var rs = create_log_table_stmt.execute();

  rs.next();
  var result = rs.getColumnValue(1);
  
  var final_query = "select " + result + " from " + TBL_NAME;
  return final_query;
$$
;

call column_list ('FOO', 'NUMBER');
```

Comment: Are you talking about information schema here ? I am not getting from your question. Can you please provide your code you are trying here.

Comment: Yeah it ist somehow about information schema. I have not tried any code yet since I simply do not know what kind of function would make sense. For example I have a table with Varchar, Integer, Date. Now I want to select all the Integer columns. Now I want to receive all columns of the datatype Varchar for example without mentioning all of them in my Select Statement.